# Empty all children of div without specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, i think this should be pretty simple but i can't seem to get it right, say i have an empty div:

`<div id='mainDiv'></div>`

This div gets filled dynamically with data from database with ajax, i want on button click to empty this div but keep one element with a specific id ex: `<div id='divToKeep'></div>`, i  tried:

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function(){
 $("#mainDiv > *:not('#divToKeep')").empty()
})
```

Now this dose empty everything but keeps the empty divs there, i want to remove everything inside `#mainDiv` but the `#divToKeep` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all the mainDiv, then get all elements inside it using children except the div you want to keep, then call remove:

```
$("#mainDiv").children(":not('#divToKeep')").remove();
```

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yzfw8atp/2/

Comment: This works but only if the `#divToKeep` has no children, if i have a <span> inside it dosen't work, is there a way to keep the div and the elements inside it?

Comment: @SomeBeginner I suggest saving the div you want to keep in a variable, removing everything from the main div and shoving the div you want to keep back in

Comment: @SomeBeginner nice point! Change find to children, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

This way, it put the divToKeep on the top level, then remove everything else inside.

```js
$('#divToKeep').appendTo('#mainDiv');  // move #divToKeep up to the body
$('#mainDiv *:not(#divToKeep):not(#divToKeep *)').remove();  // remove everything except #divToKeep and inner children
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mainDiv'>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div id="divToKeep">
        <div>
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mainDiv").children().not("#divToKeep").remove();
```